# Cleaning/deleting /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io

Tags: diskspace

I've been a Linux admin for many years but am new to the rancher environment. I'm sure this is a simple question for most but we are experiencing disk pressure and disk space issues and one of the items I found after running a df-hT is high usage of overlay filesystems located in /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io. What is the easiest way to mitigate this buildup? It's on most of our nodes. Any help would be appreciated.

Example snapshot below:

overlay                             24G   21G  2.1G  92% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/954cea5f085723d49415df2f811a637ef27fe6bf312d3abe475c69788e712141/rootfs
overlay                             24G   21G  2.1G  92% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/cb581789c4072843c26e1a56c51682b31016f3821013fa8b8a33114d03f52a46/rootfs
overlay                             24G   21G  2.1G  92% /run/k3s/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/k8s.io/ceb865ea0620cc7a117f647b8f93f19a31d71ccf6326178f839e3f59cbfb0b2a/rootfs

Comment: Hi - did you manage to get anywhere with this issue? I'm experiencing the exact same thing. Have tried to configure clean-up etc with no results. I'm running k8s and the containerd runtime.